# preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given Error

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I'm trying to insert array but I'm getting error:-

> preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

My form below like :

```
{!! Form::text('description[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm','v-model'=>'row.description']) !!}
{!! Form::text('log_time[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm','v-model'=>'row.log_time']) !!}
```

My controller store function :

```
$this->validate($request, $this->rules);
        $data = array();
        foreach($request->description as $key=>$value){
            $data[]=[
                'description'=> $value, 
        'log_time'=> $request->log_time[$key], 
        'call_id'=>$call->id,
            ];
        }
       PortLog::create($data);
```

when i check **dd($data)**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "description" => "des"
    "log_time" => ""
    "call_id" => 16
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "description" => ""
    "log_time" => "hi"
    "call_id" => 16
  ]
]
```

here what im doing wrong ?

Comment: The error is telling you. `preg_match()` (where ever that is in your code) is not being given the proper string argument. This part of your code has no `preg_match()` that I can see, so this code does not appear to be relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Anant not its error illegal string

Comment: yes sorry my bad, i was deleting my comment at that time but due to internet problem it's not deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to insert multiple `port_logs` in one statement. However, the `create()` method is only meant to create one instance of a model. You either need to use the `insert()` statement, or update your code to `foreach` through your `$data` and issue multiple `create()` statements.

```
PortLog::insert($data);

// or

foreach($data as $row) {
    PortLog::create($row);
}
```

If you just want to insert the data, and you don't want to instante a bunch of `PortLog` instances, then the `insert()` method is the way to go. If you need to instantiate a new `PortLog` instance for each row, then the `create()` method is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

check the Model fillable fields... it seems, that it missing []